# Alterar formato de data para padrão Brasileiro, datepicker JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Estou tendo um problema com formato de data, se eu coloco `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy`, meu alert me retorna invalid date, se eu retiro e deixo padrão americano ai me retorna a data.  Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Quero manter a data padrão brasileiro, porem não só com uma mascara e sim o formato em si.

[Segue o exemplo no JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/LfqwL3kx/5/)

```
<div id="teste">
  <label class="fa fa-calendar">
    <input id="startDate" name="start_at" placeholder=" " class="data-charts" type="text" value="">
  </label>
  <label class="fa fa-calendar">
    <input id="endDate" name="end_at" placeholder=" " class="data-charts" type="text" value="">
  </label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-apply">Aplicar</button>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", "-7", new Date());

    $("#endDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
             $("#startDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());


    function dateInterval() {
        var data_inicial = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
        var data_final = document.getElementById("endDate").value;

        var date1 = new Date(data_inicial);
        var date2 = new Date(data_final);
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            if(diffDays <= 30)
            {
                alert(date1);
            }else
            {
                alert(date1);
            }
    };

    $(".btn-apply").on('click',function(){
        dateInterval();
    });

});
```

Comment: Por que você não criou o exemplo aqui mesmo?

Comment: @jbueno pq não consegui, fica dando erro.

Comment: É bom colocar o código aqui, mesmo que sem snippet

Comment: @jbueno obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma solução, precisei só alterar o seu .js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#endDate")
      .datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", "-7", new Date());

    $("#endDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(selected) {
             $("#startDate")
       .datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());


    function dateInterval() {
        var data_inicial = document.getElementById("startDate").value.split("/");
    var data_final = document.getElementById("endDate").value.split("/");

        var date1 = new Date(data_inicial[2], data_inicial[1] - 1, data_inicial[0]);
        var date2 = new Date(data_final[2], data_final[1] - 1, data_final[0]);
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            if(diffDays <= 30)
            {
                alert(date1);
            }else
            {
                alert(date1);
            }
    };

    $(".btn-apply").on('click',function(){
        dateInterval();
    });

});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/LfqwL3kx/16/

Comment: Obrigado, se não for pedir muito, queria entender o que foi feito e pq? mas se não rolar tudo bem ja me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Eu usei o formato DD/MM/YY e na hora de criar a data, eu peguei dd/mm/yy (07/04/2017) e separei por "/". quando fui criar a data eu fiz new Date(data[2], data[1] -1(base 0), data[0]), se quiser entender da um BREAK POINT no objeto data.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, vou olhar mais a fundo sim.